# SET parameters to microsoft SQL server to set environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing

I have created some microsoft SQL server queries to insert values into some of my tables created.
Below are the sql queries i used.

```
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('a-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/a' ;
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('b-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/b' ;
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('c-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/c' ;
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('d-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/d' ;
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('e-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/e' ;
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('f-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/f' ;
```

Above is a piece of code which i have used for **dev**  environment.
Same code with **prod** instead of **dev** should be used for production.

Is there any way to parameterize dev and prod to achieve this?

For example lets take a single query as below:

```
INSERT INTO dev_data.extract VALUES ('a-dev-extract', '/dev/dev_data/storage/a' ;
```

Expected output for prod is as below:

```
INSERT INTO prod_data.extract VALUES ('a-prod-extract', '/prod/prod_data/storage/a' ;
```

YES I cpould use notepad to find and replace dev with prod, but the ultimate aim is to keep a common code that can be used in different environments.

I have tried as below:

```
DECLARE @env varchar;
SET @env = 'dev';
INSERT INTO @env+_data.extract VALUES ('a-+@env+-extract', '/@env/@env+_data/storage/a' ;
```

Tried with

```
SET @env = 'dev'
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' + @env + '_data.extract VALUES (''a-' + @env + '-extract'',''/' + @env + '/' + @env + '_data/storage/a'')'
```

Am getting the output as a string, not executing the query.
how to execute this query part? Instead of SELECT do we need to ADD some other command?

Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SET @env = 'dev';
SELECT CONCAT("INSERT INTO ", @env, "_data.extract VALUES (", "'a-",@env,"-extract', '/", @env, "/", @env, "_data/storage/a')") FROM DUAL
```

Snapshot:
[image]

**Updated Query:**

```
DECLARE @env varchar(10) 
DECLARE @qry varchar(200) 
SET @env = 'dev'
SET @qry = 'INSERT INTO ' + @env + '_data.extract VALUES (''a-' + @env + '-extract'',''/' + @env + '/' + @env + '_data/storage/a'')'
EXECUTE(@qry)
```

Comment: this is not working as it throws error ```Invalid object name 'DUAL'```

Comment: question is updated with the screenshots i am getting while trying this code!

Comment: I am using MySQL (as per question) and looks like you are trying in SQL Server !

Comment: sorry my mistake! Updated the question!

Comment: Am getting the output as a string, how to execute this query?

Comment: Code snippet added as per requirement

Comment: Please consider voting up and accepting it if it solved the problem !

Comment: Thank you @Soumendra Mishra.  I have around 500 insert statements to execute, For executing those statements in the solution, I have to provide all these commands in a a single line as a variable **query**. If I try to break the line after each statement, I am not able to run the query. Writing 500 queries in a single line is too tedious. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use INSERT statement with SELECT to run in one time.

Comment: But while using **SELECT** statement, the query is coming as a string value, how to execute that in one step?